# app crashes when creating view (android.view.InflateException)

Tags: java, android

```
public class ChildrensList extends Fragment   {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrens_list,container,false);
        //return rootView;

        ImageButton pigsButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pigsButton);
        ImageButton jackButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.jacksButton);
        ImageButton hansgretButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hansgretButton);
        ImageButton mermadButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mermaidButton);
        ImageButton rapButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rapunzalButton);
        ImageButton redRidButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ridingButton);
        ImageButton threeBearsButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bearsButton);
        ImageButton ugduckButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.duckButton);

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.xlophone);

        pigsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChildrensList.this.getActivity(),pigs_story.class);
                mp.start();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        jackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChildrensList.this.getActivity(), jack_beanstalk.class);
                mp.start();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        hansgretButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChildrensList.this.getActivity(), hansel_and_gretal.class);
                mp.start();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        mermadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChildrensList.this.getActivity(), mermaid.class);
                mp.start();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        rapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChildrensList.this.getActivity(), rapunzal.class);
                mp.start();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        redRidButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChildrensList.this.getActivity(), RedRidingHood.class);
                mp.start();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        threeBearsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChildrensList.this.getActivity(), ThreeBears.class);
                mp.start();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        ugduckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChildrensList.this.getActivity(), UglyDuckling.class);
                mp.start();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        return rootView; //return rootview

    }

}
```

I am having some errors appear in the console and struggling with how to resolve them, one of them is a fatal out of memory exception but there is a long list! could someone shed some light on this and help to rid the errors

```
04-19 18:47:29.392 19101-19101/com.j2d.com.bedtimestories E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.j2d.com.bedtimestories, PID: 19101
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at com.j2d.com.bedtimestories.ChildrensList.onCreateView(ChildrensList.java:25)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at com.j2d.com.bedtimestories.ChildrensList.onCreateView(ChildrensList.java:25) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at com.j2d.com.bedtimestories.ChildrensList.onCreateView(ChildrensList.java:25) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 22075212 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 17MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4225)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:589)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:347)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:343)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:339)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at com.j2d.com.bedtimestories.ChildrensList.onCreateView(ChildrensList.java:25) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Can you Post your ChildrensList.java

Comment: Also the layout xml which you are using ChildrensList.java. Looks like there is an error inflating the xml, possibly android namespace not defined

Comment: i will post the childrens list java

Comment: i havew editored and entered the java for childrens list, the error seems to point to this line..View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrens_list,container,false);

but it was working fine and this has suddenly happened

Comment: the app will run on device but when i select an option from the navigation draw, that is when the app crashes and throws the error i have posted

Comment: check the images in your xml layout. probably yo uare using big sized image resource. If so you should degrade your image before use.

Comment: i see, i thought the images would not be a problem as there not really big at all each image is 300x207

Comment: Do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of the error you posted is this:

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 22075212 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 17MB until OOM
>     [...]
>     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
>     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
>     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
>     [...]
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
>     at com.j2d.com.bedtimestories.ChildrensList.onCreateView(ChildrensList.java:25) 
>     [...]
> ```

This says your app ran out of memory.  It ran out of memory while trying to load an image, which it did when your `ChildrensList` class, in the `onCreateView()` method, called `.inflate()`.

As someone else noted in a comment on your question, it is likely that you have very large image file(s) in your app.  You should scale the images to an appropriate size to avoid this issue.

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) has an article discussing image sizes.

Comment: i see, so i should check all the images, be time consuming but guess i have no choice, will also look over the documentation thank you